# Pyserial - RS232 9600,8,N,1 send and receive data

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pyserial

I need to communicate and pass values to a serial connected device using RS232 Protocol. I need to pass commands through the 8 bytes of data and then be able to receive the response afterwards.. Im not sure how to write this in PySerial so if anyone can help out it would be great (9600 Baud, 8 data bits, No parity, and 1 stop bit.)

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')  # open serial port
print(ser.name)         # check which port was really used
ser.write(b'hello')     # write a string
ser.close()             # close port
```

The Timer Manager Command structure consists of one start byte, one command byte, five bytes of data, and a one byte checksum.  Each message packet is formatted as follows:

```
BYTE 0  BYTE 1    BYTE 2    BYTE 3     BYTE 4   BYTE 5    BYTE 6    BYTE 7
200     COMMAND   DATA1     DATA2      DATA3    DATA4     DATA5     CK SUM
```

Im looking to receive the following back from the machine: 
If command was successfully received, the Timer Manager will respond with:

```
  BYTE 0    BYTE 1  BYTE 2
   6            0       6
```

The actual data that I want to send is this 
Data i need to pass to the timer is structured this way:

```
   BYTE 0   BYTE 1  BYTE 2  BYTE 3  BYTE 4  BYTE 5  BYTE 6  BYTE 7
      200       31      4      0        0        0       0  235
```

Is this passed via bytearray ?

```
      ser.write( bytearray(200,31,4,0,0,0,0,235) );
```

Comment: Your question is woefully sort on details.  What does a response look even look like?  Is it the same format as the query?

Comment: Also, you almost certainly need to set the baudrate.

Comment: @jpkotta Just updated with what I expect to receive. Its 9600 Baud but from the Pyserial docs it seems that what I have above is 9600 by default.. any assistance with this would be fantastic.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, due to the fact that you use RS232, you must set the ASCII characters you wanna send in variables. And then, when you got in a variable all the sentence you want to send, sent it decoding it into bytes.
It would be something like this.

```
def sendserial(sendstring):
    ser.port(yourport)
    try:
        ser.open()
    except Exception as e:
        flag=1
    if ser.isOpen():
        try:
            ser.flushInput()
            ser.flushOutput()
            ser.write(bytes(sendstring,'iso-8859-1'))
            #iso 8859-1 is the only encode that works for me
            time.sleep(0.5)
            numOfLines = 0
            while True:
                resp = bytes.decode(ser.readline())
                result = ord(str(response))
                if result == ord(ACK)
                #I set previously the ACK var to the ASCII symbol that the machine returns
                    response = 'Y'
                else:
                    response = 'N'
                numOfLines = numOfLines +1
                if (numOfLines>=1):
                    break
            ser.close()
        except Exception as e1:
            print('Communication error...:' + str(e1))
    else:
        pass
    return(response)
```

Comment: Thanks man, this looks like its putting me in the right direction... Ive upated my question to show what kind of data I want to pass, should that be sent as a byte array or how do I post that to the device and get the response 6  0 6

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure if you must pass the content via bytearray, I don't know if the result string of a bytearray is the same as a string coded to bytes so...
Let me explain.

Comment: My program must send some characters, an STX, SYN, the data that I want to send, a CHECKSUM, and an ETX.
I transform this "bytes params" using the chr() function (I don't know if it works to you).
So, the STX symbol must be `STX = chr(2)` and the same way to other characters.
After that, I made my string this way `sendstring = STX+SYN+MYDATA+CHKSM+ETX` and then I send it via pyserial using the code that I have shown you.

Answer (score 2):

I generally have something like this to do binary IO over a serial port:

```
from timeit import default_timer as clk
from serial import Serial, SerialException

class TimeManager(object):
    def __init__(self, port, baudrate=9600):
        self.ser = Serial(port, baudrate=baudrate)
        self.ser.open()
        self.ser.flushInput()
        self.ser.flushOutput()

    def send(self, tx):
        tx = bytearray(tx)
        try:
            self.ser.write(tx)
            self.ser.flush()
        except SerialException as e:
            if e.args == (5, "WriteFile", "Access is denied."):
                # This occurs on win32 when a USB serial port is
                # unplugged and replugged.  It should be fixed by
                # closing and reopening the port, which should happen
                # in the error handling of our caller.
                raise IOError(errno.ENOENT, "Serial port disappeared.",
                              self.ser.portstr)
            else:
                raise

    def receive(self):
        rx = bytearray()
        delay = 10e-3 # s
        timeout = 1 # s
        end_time = clk() + timeout
        while True:
            time_remaining = end_time - clk()
            if time_remaining < 0:
                break
            rx += self.ser.read(self.ser.inWaiting())
            if 0 in rx:
                break
            time.sleep(delay)

        if time_remaining <= 0:
            raise IOError(errno.ETIMEDOUT, "Communication timed out.")

        return rx

tm = TimeManager("/dev/ttyS0")
```

My device sends null terminated messages (the `if 0 in rx:` line).  You'd have to figure out a similar condition for your messages.